# Escaping text wih google spreadsheet api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using the google spreadsheet api to update data in several spreadsheets and I need to escape some texts to use them in the following formula:

`=IFNA(FILTER('Another_SheetName'!B:B, 'Another_SheetName'!A:A=92433), HYPERLINK(url, "some_text"))`

where `Another_SheetName` is the the name of the another sheet that I get using the spreadsheet api and `some_text` a text that I want to put and I have the following two problems:

1. If `some_text` have doble quotes (`"`) I get a Formula parsing error. I can solve this putting `some_text` in cell A1 and then changing the formula to `=HYPERLINK(url, A1)`, but I want to know if there is a general way to escape the text `some_text` to use it inside the formula so that it is not necessary to use an additional cell.
2. If `Another_SheetName` can have a single quotes (`'`) I get an Unsolved Sheet Name. I can fix this replacing `'` by `''` everytime in `Another_SheetName`, but there is another case I need to consider? Or there is a way to scape the text `Another_SheetName` to use it in a formula like `=FILTER('Another_SheetName'!B:B, 'Another_SheetName'!A:A=92433)`?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OPbzXwFLpheuMJh1bIJIsXXW0zH3rUbJ6KE3WTPyN_A/edit?usp=sharing) is an example.

I update the sheet with the following code:

```
c = '''=IFNA(FILTER('Another' SheetName'!B:B, 'Another' SheetName'!A:A=92433), HYPERLINK(url, "some" text"))'''
batch_request = {'requests': [
    {'updateCells': {
        'start': {'sheetId': sheetId, 'rowIndex': i, 'columnIndex': i},
        'rows': [
            {'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'numberValue': 1}}, {'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': 'asd'}}]},
            {'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'formulaValue': c}}, {'userEnteredValue': {'formulaValue': c}}]}
        ],
        'fields': 'userEnteredValue'
    }}
]}
serviceSheet = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
serviceSheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=batch_request).execute()
```

Thank you for your help!!

---

**Update**

I decided to detail the problem in the first question with a simpler example. The problem is that I have a text with a double quote (`"`) inside and if I use the following code I get a `Formula parsing error`.

```
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
some_text = 'some "text'
c = f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", "{some_text}")'
batch_request = {'requests': [
    {'updateCells': {
        'start': {'sheetId': sheetId, 'rowIndex': 0, 'columnIndex': 0},
        'rows': [
            {'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'formulaValue': c}}]}
        ],
        'fields': 'userEnteredValue'
    }}
]}
serviceSheet = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
serviceSheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=batch_request).execute()
```

The way I find to solve this is problem is to insert the content of `some_text` in a given cell, for example `A1`, and then reference it in the above formula. Something like this:

```
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
some_text = 'some "text'
c = f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", A1)'
batch_request = {'requests': [
    {'updateCells': {
        'start': {'sheetId': sheetId, 'rowIndex': 0, 'columnIndex': 0},
        'rows': [
            {'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': some_text}}, {'userEnteredValue': {'formulaValue': c}}]},
        ],
        'fields': 'userEnteredValue'
    }}
]}
serviceSheet = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
serviceSheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=batch_request).execute()
```

but there is a way to solve this without using another cell?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current issue, about `I am using the google spreadsheet api to update data in several spreadsheets`, can you provide your current script and your request body for requesting to Sheets API?

Comment: Please share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a spreadsheet that contains enough of the original to fully represent the problem with specific, realistic data and sheet names). Formulas are written around specifics, and it is difficult to think in specifics when we're only provided with generalities.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your question, `Another_SheetName` is used as the sheet name. But from your showing script, `Another' SheetName` is used. Also, from `If Another_SheetName can have a single quote (') I get an Unsolved Sheet Name.`, I thought that your sheet name might include the single quotes.

For example, when `='Another_SheetName'!B:B` is put in a cell, it seems that the single quotations are automatically removed. For example, when `='Another SheetName'!B:B` is put in a cell, it seems that the single quotations are not removed. This situation occurs for both manually putting and putting by Sheets API.

And, for example, when `='Another' SheetName'!B:B` is used, the reference error occurs. In this case, it is required to be `='Another'' SheetName'!A1`.

From these results, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
c = '''=IFNA(FILTER('Another' SheetName'!B:B, 'Another' SheetName'!A:A=92433), HYPERLINK(url, "some" text"))'''
```

##### To:

- In this case, `'` is replaced with `''` and use it. When this script is run, `=IFNA(FILTER('Another'' SheetName'!B:B, 'Another'' SheetName'!A:A=92433), HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com", "some_text"))` is put to a cell.

  ```
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    sheetName = "Another' SheetName"
    sheetName = sheetName.replace("'", "''")
    c = f"=IFNA(FILTER('{sheetName}'!B:B, '{sheetName}'!A:A=92433), HYPERLINK(\"{url}\", \"some_text\"))"
  ```
- In this case, `INDIRECT` is used. When this script is run, `=IFNA(FILTER(INDIRECT("'Another' SheetName'!B:B"), INDIRECT("'Another' SheetName'!A:A")=92433), HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com", "some_text"))` is put to a cell.

  ```
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    sheetName = "Another' SheetName"
    c = f'=IFNA(FILTER(INDIRECT("\'{sheetName}\'!B:B"), INDIRECT("\'{sheetName}\'!A:A")=92433), HYPERLINK("{url}", "some_text"))'
  ```

### Added:

About your updated question,

When you want to use the following script,

```
some_text = 'some "text'
c = f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", "{some_text}")'
```

How about the following modification?

```
some_text = 'some "text'.replace('"', '""')
c = f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", "{some_text}")'
```

In this modification, `"` is replaced with `""`. By this, the text of `some "text` can be used.

By the way, about your following 2nd script, the formula is put to the cell "A1". But, the formula uses the value of the cell "A1". In this case, the formula doesn't work. Please be careful about this.

Comment: I have try the approach of using `INDIRECT`, but in case if sheetName = '''Another' "SheetName''' (sheetName have a doble quote `"`character) it fails. In case of doing `sheetName = sheetName.replace("'", "''")`, is there another possible case that does not work? Maybe another special character or something else.

Comment: And what about my first question? About making HYPERLINK with `"` character, somethin like this:
`url = "https://stackoverflow.com"`
`some_text = 'some" text'`
`c = f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", "{some_text}")'`

Comment: @Diego Silvera Thank you for replying. About `I have try the approach of using INDIRECT, but in case if sheetName = '''Another' "SheetName''' (sheetName have a doble quote "character) it fails. In case of doing sheetName = sheetName.replace("'", "''"), is there another possible case that does not work? Maybe another special character or something else.`, if `INDIRECT` is used, I proposed `c = f'=IFNA(FILTER(INDIRECT("\'{sheetName}\'!B:B"), INDIRECT("\'{sheetName}\'!A:A")=92433), HYPERLINK("{url}", "some_text"))'`. Can you test it?

Comment: @Diego Silvera About `And what about my first question? About making HYPERLINK with " character, somethin like this: url = "https://stackoverflow.com" some_text = 'some" text' c = f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", "{some_text}")'`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I have to confirm whether my understanding your question is correct. I thought that your question was "I believe your goal is as follows." in my answer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I posted an update to the first question with a better description of the problem

Comment: @Diego Silvera Thank you for replying. About your updated question, I added the answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @Diego Silvera Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.